# int/uint data type with ether unit suffixes

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm using the Remix editor and I have a nonsense function that takes a `int` data type as an argument that simply just returns it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract someContract {

    function doSomething (int a) public pure returns (int) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

When I pass in a whole number for example, `1`, I get back:

```
{
    "0": "int256: 1"
}
```

which makes sense to me.

**But** when I pass in a number with an ether unit, for example, `1 ether`, I get back:

```
{
    "0": "int256: 270867"
}
```

Or if I try `1 wei`, I get back:

```
{
    "0": "int256: 4358"
}
```

Is this a Remix bug, or is there something special about `1 ether == int256(270867)` or `1 wei == int256(4358)`?

This is how I'm passing these values.

https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js

[image: debug output]
[image: input of 1 ether]

Comment: Can you describe how you're passing in 1 ether or 1 wei? Via another contract? Can you share that code too?

Comment: For comparison, if I write `function test() public pure returns (uint256) { return 1 ether; }` and execute it in Remix, I get back `uint256: 1000000000000000000`.

Comment: @smarx, I tried your function and it worked great.  But when I modify your function to `function test(uint256 a) public pure returns (uint256) { return a; }` and take a `1 ether` input, I still get `{
    "0": "int256: 270867"
}` back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from you screenshot like you're passing a string: `"1 ether"`. I'm not sure how Remix is interpreting that, but you can see from the "decoded input" that it's indeed sending the value 270867.

If you try "hello" instead, you'll see the value 186334 is sent.

I would say this should be an error in Remix, since you're not passing a valid `uint256`. I don't know if `web3.js` treats strings the same way.

If you want to pass 1 ether via `web3`, you can use `web3.toWei(1, 'ether')`.

**UPDATE**

I've tracked this down to `ethereumjs-abi`, which is used under the hood in Remix to do the ABI encoding:

```
> const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');
> parseInt(abi.rawEncode(['uint256'], ['hello']).toString('hex'), 16);    
186334
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've further tracked this down to `bn.js`, which is used under the hood in `ethereumjs-abi`:

```
> new BN('hello')
<BN: 2d7de>
> 0x2d7de
186334
```

**UPDATE 3**

The issue is probably in `parseBase`: https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/blob/master/lib/bn.js#L245. But essentially, we're passing invalid data (violating some assumptions made in `bn.js`), since it's expecting a number. What's missing is some parameter validation.

Comment: Great investigative work!  But in the docs on http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html, it says that "A literal number can take a suffix of wei, finney, szabo or ether to convert between the subdenominations of Ether".  Isn't `1 ether` then considered a valid `uint` data type?

Comment: Yes, in Solidity. But you're typing JSON into a web app.